# prolog Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated error

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I have to write a prolog query to print family details of each family where children’s total income is more than their parents, I've written but I'm getting this error

```
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [3] _1770 is _1776+0
   [2] totalx([person(_1844,_1846,_1848,...)],_1834) at  line 50
   [1] '<meta-call>'((...,...)) <foreign>
```

This is the base code:

```
family(person( john, cohen, date(17,may,1990), unemployed), person( lily, cohen, 
date(9,may,1990), unemployed),[ ] ).
family(person( john, armstrong, date(7,may,1988), unemployed), person( lily, Armstrong, 
date(29,may,1961), unemployed), [ ] ).
family(person( eric, baily, date(7,may,1963), works( bbc, 2200)), person( grace, baily, 
date(9,may,1965), works( ntu, 1000)), [person( louie, baily, date(25,may,1983), unemployed) ] ).
family(person( eric, baily, date(7,may,1963), works( acc, 21200)), person( grace, baily, 
date(9,may,1965), works( ntnu, 12000)), [person( louie, baily, date(25,may,1983), unemployed) ] ).
family(person( eric, fox, date(27,may,1970), works( bbc, 25200)), person( grace, fox, 
date(9,may,1971), works( ntbu, 13000)), [person( louie, fox, date(5,may,1993), unemployed) ] ).

    husband(X) :- family(X, _, _).
    wife(X) :- family(_, X, _).
    child(X) :- family(_, _, Children), member(X, Children).

    salary(person(_, _, _, works(_, S)), S).
    salary(person(_, _, _, unemployed), 0).
```

This is my code for the requirement:

```
    48-totalx([],0).
    49-totalx([Person|L],Sum):-salary(Person,S),totalx(L,Rest),
    50-Sum is S+Rest
```

And the query for the requirement:

```
family(Husband,Wife,Child),totalx(Children,IChildren),totalx([Husband],IHusband), 
totalx([Wife],IWife),IChildren > IHusband+IWife.
```

can someone explain to me why it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you get some warnings? Like about the variable `Armstrong`?

Comment: Try `totalx(Children,IChildren)´ alone.

Comment: No, i didn't just the Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated error

Comment: i got Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [2] _1352 is _1358+0
   [1] totalx([person(_1426,_1428,_1430,...)],_1416) at  line 51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

- The first one is the atom `armstrong`, in the second clause of predicate `family/3`, that must start with a lowercase letter.
- The second one is the variable `Child`, in the first goal of the query, that must be `Children` (the instantiation error is due to the fact that variable `Children` is not instantiated in the second goal of the query).

```
family(person(john, cohen, date(17,may,1990), unemployed),
       person(lily, cohen, date( 9,may,1990), unemployed),
       []).

family(person(john, armstrong, date( 7,may,1988), unemployed),
       person(lily, armstrong, date(29,may,1961), unemployed), % lowercase
       []).

family(person(eric,  baily, date(7,may,1963), works( bbc, 2200)),
       person(grace, baily, date(9,may,1965), works( ntu, 1000)),
       [person( louie, baily, date(25,may,1983), unemployed)]).

family(person(eric,  baily, date(7,may,1963), works( acc, 21200)),
       person(grace, baily, date(9,may,1965), works( ntnu, 12000)),
       [person(louie, baily, date(25,may,1983), unemployed)] ).

family(person(eric,  fox, date(27,may,1970), works( bbc, 25200)),
       person(grace, fox, date( 9,may,1971), works( ntbu, 13000)),
       [person(louie, fox, date(5,may,1993), unemployed)] ).


husband(X) :- family(X, _, _).
wife(X) :- family(_, X, _).
child(X) :- family(_, _, Children), member(X, Children).

salary(person(_, _, _, works(_, S)), S).
salary(person(_, _, _, unemployed), 0).


totalx([], 0).
totalx([Person|L],Sum) :-
    salary(Person, S),
    totalx(L, Rest),
    Sum is S + Rest.
```

Query:

```
?- family(Husband,Wife,Children), totalx(Children,IChildren),totalx([Husband],IHusband),totalx([Wife],IWife),IChildren > IHusband+IWife.
false.
```

The query fails because there is no family where the children earn more than their parents. However, removing that constraint, the query works properly and produces some answers.

```
?- family(Husband,Wife,Children), totalx(Children,IChildren),totalx([Husband],IHusband),totalx([Wife],IWife).
Husband = person(john, cohen, date(17, may, 1990), unemployed),
Wife = person(lily, cohen, date(9, may, 1990), unemployed),
Children = [],
IChildren = IHusband, IHusband = IWife, IWife = 0 ;

Husband = person(john, armstrong, date(7, may, 1988), unemployed),
Wife = person(lily, armstrong, date(29, may, 1961), unemployed),
Children = [],
IChildren = IHusband, IHusband = IWife, IWife = 0 
...
```